# tmux segfaults on send-key after upgrading to 2.9a

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, segmentation-fault

I just upgraded an Ubuntu Server from 18.10 to 19.04 and then to 19.10. I think that this upgrade also upgraded `tmux` to a newer version.

Since then my `tmux` scripts, which build some dashboards, are no longer working.

When issuing a command like

```
tmux send-keys "echo 'test'" C-m;
```

I get a `lost server` message.

This happens when nothing has attached to the session which contains the pane which is being targeted.

When I start a session and attach to it, then `send-keys` does work.

The syslog contains the following entry

> Mar 12 23:27:33 machine kernel: [   27.074805] tmux: server[2657]:
>   segfault at 751 ip 000056042469f029 sp 00007ffe602aa6f0 error 4 in
>   tmux[560424675000+62000]

This is what my creation script looks like, it is invoked in `crontab` as `@reboot`, but the problem also exists when manually executing it.

```
SESSION=stuff

tmux new-session -d -s $SESSION -n 'homepage'
tmux split-window -h -p 50
tmux select-pane -t 1; tmux send-keys "./lhp.sh" C-m;
tmux select-pane -t 2; tmux send-keys "./lnginx.sh" C-m;
tmux split-window -v -p 50
tmux select-pane -t 3; tmux send-keys "./lsmr.sh" C-m;

tmux new-window -t $SESSION -n 'shells'
tmux split-window -h -p 50

tmux select-window -t :1;
```

And at some later point in time (hours or days) I invoke

```
tmux attach-session -t stuff
```

to view the content.

Does anyone know I can continue using it as I used to?

Answer (score 0):

If I replace your "./l*" scripts with "sleep 10", the script does not crash with tmux 3.1-rc, so either this is a bug in 2.9a, or the problem is in one of your scripts.

Of course, the script doesn't work either - you can't mix `new -t` and `-n`. Do you mean `-s` instead of `-t`? And you probably need to add `-d` or the rest of the script won't run. Also your pane numbers are wrong - you only split once, but then target panes 1 and 2 when only 0 and 1 exist. So I suspect this is not the script you are actually using.

Anyway tmux 2.9a is no longer supported, so your best bet is to build tmux 3.0a or 3.1-rc and see if the problem still exists. If it does, you can open an issue at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues, preferably with the script you are really using and some tmux log files.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding `-d` and  `-s` you're right. It is a snippet of the entire file, and I only modified the `new-session`, forgetting about the flags. The issue is not with the scripts, even `tmux send-keys "echo 'test'" C-m;` fails. I will try building it.

Comment: Also, this even happens when I don't use `tmux select-pane -t 1;`, but just let `send-keys` go to whatever it goes to when new panes are created. (I'm splitting twice), AFAIK the pane numbering is 1-based. It used to work, so I doubt that those indices are the cause.

Comment: See the other answer. The fix didn't make it into 3.0 so you will need to upgrade to master or 3.1-rc, or you can just change so your `.tmux.conf` file does not generate any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `tmux`.

The issue is being tracked here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tmux/+bug/1847484 and that one is referenced here https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1980

The fix is of low priority since it is a "bad config" issue, so it still exists in at least 3.0-rc5.

Basically it is this problem:

> So, the crash seems to happen when sending keystrokes to a frame that
>   is still showing error messages from parsing the configuration.

So you need to ensure that you have a valid `tmux` config file which does not throw errors, like

```
.tmux.conf:33: invalid option: pane-border-fg
```

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten about this completely.